# Screen orientation messes up after UIActivityViewController

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, orientation, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm at my wits end with this screen rotation problem. If you could please take a look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it. I have stripped my project down to its simplest form, here is what is happening:

- run app, the screen will flash red (to indicate its drawing and
  updating)
- click anywhere in app to open the UIActivityViewController
- dialog opens, click on mail, click cancel, delete draft
- my window is now rotated and on the left side of the screen

I have tried adding shouldAutorotate, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation, supportedInterfaceOrientations, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to all of my views, but it's not working.

I must be missing something, what is it?

Here is my xcode project containing source code
http://www.qfpost.com/file/d?g=eyG4h6u2n

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by adding a custom navigation view controller to control the rotations.

Comment: Can you please post the custom navigation view controller's code. So someone can refer your answer. Otherwise your answer is helpless.